# Objective-C source code debug: Thread Error

Tags: objective-c, thread-exceptions

I cannot seem to solve this problem, im not sure what it is at this point but the tread error wont go away. I cant seem to find what im doing wrong. 
This code may be a handful to read (sorry) but its very simple. I'am basically invoking a function from main and passing an array of function values, from there im passing two fractions at a time to a method so it find the LCM(least common multiple) using the denominators and return the value. But a thread error seems to be occurring at the call to the findLCM method from function at the point of where the method is declared.

```
@interface Fraction: NSObject
@property int numerator, denominator;

-(Fraction *)findLCM:(Fraction *)fraction withXFractions:(int)Xfraction;

   @implementation Fraction 

 -(Fraction *)findLCM:(Fraction *)fraction withXFractions:(int)Xfraction{
 int lcmOfFraction = 0;
 int a, b;
 a =  fraction.denominator;
 b =  self.denominator;
 int max =(a>b) ? a : b; // get max value out of the two denominators.

   for (int i = 0; i < Xfraction; i++) {
    while(1)                       /* Always true. */
    {
        if(max%a==0 && max%b==0)
        {  lcmOfFraction = max;
            break;   /* while loop terminates. */
        }     

        ++max;
    }
}
    Fraction *lcmDenominator = [Fraction new];
    [lcmDenominator setTo:0 over:max]; //passing just LCM (denominator of 2 fractions)
    return lcmDenominator; 
}



Fraction *addFraction(Fraction **arrayOfFractions, int arraySize) {
    Fraction *LCM = [[Fraction alloc] init];   
    int lcmOfFractions = 0;
    [LCM setTo:0 over:1];

 for (int i = 0; i <= arraySize; i++) {
    LCM = [LCM findLCM:arrayOfFractions[i] withXFractions:4];   
    //^gets the LCM (the common denominator)
}
  return  LCM;

}

     int main () {
    @autoreleasepool {

 [frac1 setTo:2 over:12]; [frac2 setTo:2 over:4];
 [frac3 setTo:6 over:8];  [frac4 setTo:8 over:3];

Fraction __autoreleasing *arrayOfFractions[4] = {frac1, frac2, frac3, frac4   };
Fraction *LCMFraction = addFraction(arrayOfFractions, 4); 
 //common LCM return 
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You create no threads in this code. When asking a question like this you should clearly explain what the error is, and what you have tried to find its source. People may then be able to help you.

Some hints/suggestions:

- use breakpoints to stop your code during execution to allow you to examine the values of your variables
- pay close attention to indexing operations, you are using a C array and those do not do bounds checking
- ask whether using a C array here, rather than an `NSArray` is your best choice. Note there is *nothing wrong with using C arrays when appropriate*.
- `__autoreleasing` probably doesn't mean what you think it does, it is rare to see this used explicitly in user code.

If you have a specific question when you've got further ask a new question on SO, somebody will probably be able to help you out.

HTH

Comment: sorry about the lack of explanation. But i seem to having an error at the point where the method of findLCM is declared after its been called from the function not sure if it has something to do with the object being returned or the declaration itself. Any help would would be useful.

Comment: @HumzaaChoudryy - "or the declaration itself" - if a *declaration* passes the compiler then it cannot be the source of a run time error (think about it). Have you added break points and stepped through your code watching the values of your variables as you do so? What about checking those indexing operations? Etc. you should soon discover your error by doing this.